Problem proving tempered distibution
Given
$$ T = (x^2+x+1)\delta' $$
How can I prove that $T$ is a tempered distribution?
The step that I took are as follows.
I define $ f(x)=x^2+x+1 $ and I used Leibniz's rule that states:
$$ \dfrac{d}{dx}(f\delta)=f'\delta + \delta'f $$
So now I can write
$$ (f\,\delta', \phi) = (f\,\delta' + f'\delta - f'\delta, \phi) = (\frac{d}{dx}(f\,\delta),\phi)-(f'\,\delta,\phi) $$
And now I can use the property of derivation and I have:
$$ (\frac{d}{dx}(f\,\delta),\phi)-(f'\,\delta,\phi) = -(f\,\delta,\,\phi') - (f'\,\delta,\phi) $$
And then I can move $f$ to get
$$ (f\,\delta,\,\phi') - (f'\,\delta,\phi) = -(\delta,\;f\,\phi')-(\delta,\;f'\phi) $$
And now I'm stuck, I don't know if I should use the fact that $\dfrac{d}{dx}(f\phi)=f'\phi + \phi'f$ and write
$$ -(\delta,\;f\,\phi')-(\delta,\;f'\phi) = - (\delta,\;\frac{d}{dx}(f\phi)) $$
Ore evaluate $f$ and $f'$, ore something else. Any help would be much appreciated.

What is your definition of a tempered distribution? It would help to start there so you know what you should be working towards.

@NinadMunshi I'm trying to manipulate the operations so that I can have a form where on the left side I have a tempered distribution (for example $\delta$ or any derivative of $\delta$) or a linear combination of tempered distribution, and on the right hand side a test function $\phi$.

@NinadMunshi Maybe knowing that $f(0)=1$ and $f'(0)=1$ I can write $ (\delta,,f\phi') = (\delta,\phi')$, and same thing on the other one, writing $ (\delta,f'\phi) = (\delta,\phi) $ so that the last expression is equal to $-(\delta, \phi' - \phi)$. The right hand side is a test function because $\phi$ is a test function. Is that a solution?

A suggestion is to do it in several small steps:

Show that $\delta$ is a tempered distribution ("t.d." below).
Show that if $U$ is a t.d. then $U'$ is also a t.d.
Show that if $U$ is a t.d. then $xU$ is also a t.d.
Show that if $U_1$ and $U_2$ are t.d. then $U_1+U_2$ is also a t.d.
Show that if $U$ is a t.d. then
$(\sum_{k=1}^{n} x^k)U = \sum_{k=1}^{n} x^k U.$

From the above you then get that

$\delta$ is a t.d.
$\delta'$ is a t.d.
$x\delta'$ is a t.d.
$x^2\delta' = x(x\delta')$ is a t.d.
$(x^2+x+1)\delta' = x^2\delta' + x\delta' + \delta'$ is a t.d.

